# TypeError matplotlib in a python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib

I am developing a python code with a GUI written by Qt5. The GUI already contains a 2D plot. I want to open a figure in a new window to plot something. using matplotlib.pyplot.figure produces an error. Here's the function to produce the plot:

```
def deformed_mesh_3D(model, scale):
    x, y = model.nodal_coordinates
    z = list()
    z_reference = list()
    for node in model.nodes:
        if node.results.get('w') is None:
            return
        z.append(node.results.get('w')*scale)
        z_reference.append(0.0)

    triangles = list()
    for element in model.elements:
        if type(element)==QuadPlateBending:
            index1 = element.nodes[0].id - 1
            index2 = element.nodes[1].id - 1
            index3 = element.nodes[2].id - 1
            index4 = element.nodes[3].id - 1
            triangles.append([index1, index2, index3])
            triangles.append([index1, index3, index4])
    triangulation = tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles)

    fig = plt.figure(FigureClass=Figure)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_trisurf(triangulation, z, cmap='jet')
    ax.plot_trisurf(triangulation, z_reference, alpha=0.33, color='grey')
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.margins(0.1)
    ax.invert_xaxis()
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set(xlabel='< X >', ylabel='< Y >', zlabel='< Z >')
    plt.show()
```

This produces the following error.

```
File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 525, in figure
**kwargs)
File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3218, in new_figure_manager
return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3224, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
canvas = cls.FigureCanvas(figure)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**UPDATE:** After some extensive debugging, the problem turned out to be backend related. The backend used in the GUI is Qt5Agg, and for some reason, when used to have an external plot, it gives the aforementioned error. I have tried `plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')` and it gave an import error. I commented out the lines that raise this error from the source code of pyplot ([here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/135bab0d57536d80263972ec5fc8be9b156205f7/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L218)). Obviously, it is not a good idea to do it this way, but it had successfully produced the plot window. Is there a way to dynamically switch the backend from 'Qt5Agg' to 'TkAgg'?

Comment: Can you explain what `plt.figure(FigureClass=Figure)` is supposed to do?

Comment: It's the same as `plt.figure()`. I was trying to see if the code is changing the default `FigureClass` argument in the function call.

Comment: Ok, so it's irrelevant for this problem?! Instead provide a [mcve] that people can run.

Comment: Sorry that I cannot provide a minimal version producing the same problem, since it is backend-related. Please, kindly, check the update in the post.

Comment: I don't see why this being backend-related prevents from creating a [mcve]. What I can say at this point is that it is always possible to switch backends *before* having plotted something. If you already have an open figure, switching backends will not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) `FigureClass` argument should be a subclass of `Figure`. By default it will use `Figure` so no need to specify this. And this will solve the error, I think.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to see if the code is changing the default `FigureClass` argument in the function call. This does not solve the problem, unfortunately.